# How in python to save and retrieve data to and from a csv file and into a dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

In advance, this is my first question here, so excuse me if I am unclear or excessive in my question. I am new to coding in general, but I was trying to make a program that is a catalogue for computer parts, just to practice coding. Currently I have it setup so that when I enter a new item, it goes through a class and the item is given an ID #, name, cost, etc... The computer part is put into a dictionary with ID # as the key, and the value being the class object. I plan on later being able to sort the different parts by the different attributes like name, cost, etc... I am trying to save the dictionary to a csv file so that each time I start/end the program, my computer parts from the previous time still exist. I was trying to accomplish this by having the csv file be imported to the dictionary every time the program launches, so then I can lookup or edit any previous parts. Then once I have made any changes, the csv file would be written again with the updated information. So currently if I choose choice "7" after making only 1 part, it acts as an update and should send every thing in the dictionary (just the one part) to the csv file.

```
            elif choice == "7":
            with open('part_list.csv', 'w', ) as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                for key, value in part_dict.items():
                    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

When I do this, the csv file looks like:

```
1,<__main__.Computer_Part object at 0x000001A723F6DFA0>
```

I then want to be able to exit the program, and when I come back I want to be able to still have this part, so I would then import the information from the csv file back into the original dictionary (that is now blank since I reopened the program). I tried to accomplish this with the following code:

```
def import_part_dict():
with open('part_list.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    part_dict = {}
    for row in reader:
        key, value = row
        part_dict[key] = row
    return part_dict
```

Doing this however, returns "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)". I am not sure why this does not add the csv file values back to the dictionary. Any help would be much appreciated. This code was written in Python 3.9, if that changes anything.

Comment: it seems you have to convert your data to strings before saving in CSV. Python will not do it automatically for you. If you have objects with `name, cost,` then probably you need `.writerow([key, value.name, value,cost])` instead of `.writerow([key, value])`

Comment: maybe use `print(row)` to see what you get when you read file. It helps you to see problem. You could also open CSV file in text editor to see what you saved.

Comment: Hey Furas, does the fact that the value is a class object change that? The cvs file doesn't show "1, IntelCore, CPU, 25" for example. Instead it shows "1, class_object" with 1 being the key (ID #) so I believe all that information like the name, type, and price is saved inside of that class_object.

Comment: problem is that you keep it in class and Python doesn't have method to convert class to list with all values from class. You have do it on your own - `writerow([key, value.id, value.name, value,cost, ...])` and the same will be when you read it from file. It would be better to use pandas for it. Or keep it in database (ie. SQLite). Both (pandas, database) have many useful function to sort, filter. Normally you would have to write all functions from scratch.

Comment: @furas Thanks. I saw someone else has recommended pandas, so I am taking a look at that. Will using pandas, mean I will not need to use the class?

Comment: with `pandas` you don't need class because it keeps data in table (in separated columns) like Excel - `pandas` has even method to save it as Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a dict is going to be cumbersome for this sort of thing. I would strongly suggest that you utilize pandas to bring csv data into a dataframe. With the dataframe you can sort, add/remove stuff, run queries, regex, et al.

```
import pandas as pd

path_to_csv = '/my/path/to/csv/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)

>>> df
  name     item  id
0  one  item001   1
1  two  item002   2

>>> df.iloc[0]
name        one
item    item001
id            1
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

https://www.learnpython.org/en/Pandas_Basics

Comment: The intro class I took did not cover pandas, so I will definitely take a look at that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

`items()` returns `dict_items` instead of `list`. To convert it into pairs of key and value to do just `list(foo.items())`. But this list still list of tuples, like this:

```
[(foo,1),(bar,2),(baz,3)]
```

It needs to be flatten into just a list. There are many ways to accomplish it, but I show a example using `itertools`.

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain(*{'a':1,'b':2}.items()))

# ['a', 1, 'b', 2]
```

Comment: when you use `items()` with `for key, value` then you get items ony-by-one and you don't need `list()`

Comment: Sorry, I said unreliable thing.

Comment: OP doesn't have `{'a':1,'b':2}` which doesn't need to be flatten to save it - it has `{'a':Computer_Part_Class,'b':Computer_Part_Class}` and it needs method to get values from class `Computer_Part_Class` to get `Computer_Part_Class.id, Computer_Part_Class.name, Computer_Part_Class.cost`